# Workflow or what ? - Help understanding the good way to create it

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I'm using SPD to create my workflow. I was asking to create a process like this (holidays) :

1. **People1** create a item in a custom list, and **People1** fill a field
   with a people picker with **People2**.
2. Then a mail is sent to **People2** to inform that **People1** create an
   item, and it needs to be Approuved/Rejected. In the mail, would be
   great if there's a link to the **People1**'s item.
3. Then **People2** Approuve/Reject the demand, and a mail is sent to
   **People1** for information. Also, a mail might be send to **People3**, with
   demand information (who, when, approuved/rejected by who, and link
   to the item).
4. To finish, **People3** must be able to print the item (and the mail that
   said if app/reject).
5. Last action, **People3** set the item to "*Closed*" a no one should modify
   it now.

So first, I hope I'm understable enough.
Then, I guess a workflow (or maybe 2) is the good way to complete my need.

Am I wrong ? And do you have a link that can help me creating this (these) workflow(s) as it must do a lot of thing (*imo*).

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You should go creating Sharepoint designer workflow. If would suffice your requirements as far as i understand. Otherwise you can go for more customize workflows using Visual studio.

For Creating Sharepoint designer Workflows:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/16/a-sample-approval-workflow-which-can-be-recalled-by-initiator.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/11/22/example-workflow-with-app-step-usage.aspx

For Visual studio you can refer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163199(v=office.15).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163917(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer. As i'm not a dev. at all, I'll go with your first link. I'll come back if any question. Thanks.